# Reading individual elements from a arrow::Array column using GetScalar() not compiling

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to read a parquet file using the Apache Arrow library. The following code opens a parquet file and attempts to read its rows using a arrow::RecordBatchReader. But it fails to build with the message:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘using element_type = class arrow::Array’ {aka ‘class arrow::Array’}
   39 |           auto value = record_batch->column(0)->GetScalar(i);
```

The code I am working with is:

```
void read_parquet(std::string file_name) {

    arrow::Status st;
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> infile;

    PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(infile, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(file_name));

    std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> reader;
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::OpenFile(infile, arrow::default_memory_pool(), &reader));

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatchReader> record_batch_reader;
    reader->GetRecordBatchReader(&record_batch_reader);
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> record_batch;
    while (true) {
      arrow::Status status = record_batch_reader->ReadNext(&record_batch);

      if (!status.ok() || record_batch == nullptr) {
          break;  // Exit the loop if there are no more batches or if an error occurs
      }

      // Iterate over rows in the current record batch
      for (int64_t i = 0; i < record_batch->num_rows(); i++) {
          // Get the values from the first column of the record batch
          auto value = record_batch->column(0)->GetScalar(i);
      }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: IMHO you need to #include the header file where class arrow::Array is defined.